# Multiple annotations at same coordinate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotation

Whenever user do a long press on the map.I want to add Pin point into the MAP.It's working perfectly.

Now **I want to add annotation to the same coordinate**.

But this time obviously I can't able to add Since there is a annotation already User's interaction will go to the annotation button action.

How can i overcome this problem

I've already referred the previous questions sine they are adding annotation programmatically it didn't help me.

I hope there will be some easy solution.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be my logic is helpful in your case.

**1)** I am sure that You was added LongPressGesture or anyThing action which has action with specific duration.
**2)** Run `NSTimer` with it's `timeInterval` according to LongPressGesture duration

```
 EX. = >
         - If LongPressGesture duration 0.25 then
         - Then create   `NSTimer` with it's `timeInterval` 0.25 with REPEAT = "NO"
```

And put you logic *(about add annotation to the same coordinate)* in `NSTimer'S` **Method**.